# Mapping a json correctly using Restkit

Tags: objective-c, json, post, mapping, restkit

I have the following JSON

```
{

    "data": {
        "status": 200,
        "message": "OK",
        "text": "Succesvol ingelogd.",
        "user": {
            "cu_id": 1,
            "cu_status_id": 0,
            "cu_company_id": 1,
            "cu_function_id": 1,
            "cu_department_id": 1,
            "cu_email": "info@sanmax.be",
            "cu_first_name": "First",
            "cu_last_name": "Last",
            "cu_phone_intern": "",
            "cu_mobile_phone": "",
            "cu_street": "",
            "cu_number": "",
            "cu_bus": "",
            "cu_postalcode": "",
            "cu_location": "",
            "cu_country": "",
            "cu_birthdate": "0000-00-00",
            "cu_picture": "",
            "cu_comment": "",
            "cu_ison_reminder_email": 0,
            "cu_ison_reminder_app": 0,
            "cu_ison_reminder_web": 0,
            "cu_first_use": 1
        },
        "company": {
            "c_id": 1,
            "c_name": "Sanmax",
            "c_phone": "089 68 06 39",
            "c_fax": "089 856 929",
            "c_website": "www.sanmax.be"
        },
        "function": {
            "cf_id": 1,
            "cf_name": "Developer"
        },
        "department": {
            "cd_id": 1,
            "cd_name": "Development"
        },
        "statuses": [
            {
                "cs_id": 3,
                "cs_company_id": 1,
                "cs_name": "Bezet",
                "cs_default": 1,
                "cs_image": ""
            },
            {
                "cs_id": 1,
                "cs_company_id": 1,
                "cs_name": "Online",
                "cs_default": 0,
                "cs_image": ""
            },
            {
                "cs_id": 2,
                "cs_company_id": 1,
                "cs_name": "Offline",
                "cs_default": 0,
                "cs_image": ""
            },
            {
                "cs_id": 4,
                "cs_company_id": 1,
                "cs_name": "Afwezig",
                "cs_default": 0,
                "cs_image": ""
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

I know how I should map if I only got one object. Here I have a data object. If everthing is Ok, I got a data.status 200 inside the data object, but I also get a userObject, a companyObject, a functionObject, a departmentObject and a statusObject (which contains also other objects).

But If i don't get a 200 data.status code, Let's say I got a 404 data.status code. I only get a status code, and a message.

How should I map it inside restkit?

Any help, kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server shouldn't respond with a status 200 if there has been an error. Therefore, as far as I know, this will never map to an error in RestKit 0.20.

Comment: First of all I appreciate your help. At the moment I got a better understanding of restKit now. The code I wrote is not the best RestKit code I think, but it is a start!